# Usage of "smash hit"

Tags: phrase-usage

Is this phrase used somehow incorrectly? Because the ([Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Smash%20Hit)) defines: "that which is very successful".
Therefore, it is wrong to use this phrase with love because it sounds like something weird. I'm right?

> Love is not only something you feel, 
>   it is something you do. 
>   Well, if you want to make it a smash hit kinda thing.

Stumbled on the Internet.

Comment: Note that the Urban Dictionary is a wiki written by amateurs and is not necessarily reliable. I would recommend cross-checking a [few other more reputable dictionaries](https://onelook.com/?w=smash+hit&ls=a), and seeing what they say.

Comment: There are the same values

Comment: I see no contradiction. Perhaps it is saying that true love isn't a meek and passive experience, but is what you make it: the harder you work at it, the better it gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usage is fine, if a little colloquial. The last sentence of your quote means "Well, if you want to make it very successful."